# Parsing Headers from a POST request response in RestSharp

Tags: c#, post, restsharp

I am sending a Post request using RestSharp:

```
var response = await this.SendRequestAsync<dynamic>(Method.POST, $"myAPIurl",body,false);
```

Now I want to get the headers from the response I get from the above request.
But I am only able to get the response body.

My code to get response is as follows:

```
log.Info($"Payload : {response.Payload}");
```

Can anyone please help me in getting the headers

Comment: what API are you calling? you shouldn't need to parse headers from the response...

Comment: I need something from the response headers for my next API call.

Basically my cuurent API gives a JOB-ID in the headers , I need that JOB ID for my next API call